# how to store data in same key in dictionary using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary

This is my output, in place of `[object,object]`, it should give value but I am unable to get value.

```
[ 'CME,ES,201703': '0[object Object][object Object][object Object]',
  'CME,ZB,201703': '0[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]',
  'LME,ZB,201703': '0[object Object][object Object]',
  'LME,ES,201703': '0[object Object]',
  'CME,ES,201706': '0[object Object]' ]
```

F**or this I m writing the pc of code**

```
var response = result['s:Envelope']['s:Body'][0].OrderReportResponse[0].obj[0];
            var marketOrder = response['a:MarketOrder'];
            // Storing values in Dictionary
            var dict1 = [];
            var dict2 = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < marketOrder.length; i++) {
                var keys1 = []; // Storing multiple keys in 1 object
                var keys = [];
                // if (dict1.length === 0) {
                keys.push({
                    k1: marketOrder[i]['a:SecurityExchange'],
                    k2: marketOrder[i]['a:Symbol'],
                    k3: marketOrder[i]['a:MaturityMonthYear']
                });
                if (keys1.indexOf(keys[0].k1) && keys1.indexOf(keys[0].k2) && keys1.indexOf(keys[0].k3)) {
                    keys1.push(keys[0].k1, keys[0].k2, keys[0].k3);
                }
                for (var k1 in keys1[0]) {
                    var dict = {};
                    dict[keys1] = marketOrder[i];
                    if (dict1.indexOf(dict)) {
                        dict1.push(dict);
                    }
                }
            }
 var targetObj = [];
            var targetObj1 = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < dict1.length; i++) {
                for (var key in dict1[i]) {

                    if (!targetObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        targetObj[key]= 0;
                        //targetObj1.push(targetObj);
                    }
   targetObj[key] += (dict1[i][key]);
}}
  console.log(targetObj);
```

Where I am doing mistake because of that I am unable to fetch data in same key.

Comment: Your first snippet is syntactically invalid. Is that an array or an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, your use of `array.indexOf()` is not correct. It returns the index if found, or `-1` if the passed item is *not* found. So currently all of your conditionals will fail if the item specified is found at position 0, but will pass if either the item is not found or has an index > 0.

Secondly, if you want to store multiple items, just use an array for the value and just push items to it when you find that the key exists. If the key doesn't exist, then set it to an array containing the first item. For example:

```
if (!Array.isArray(targetObj[key]))
  targetObj[key] = [ dict1[i][key] ];
else
  targetObj[key].push(dict1[i][key]);
```

Comment: bt i want that in dictionary, and how to use Array for that.

Comment: var targetObj = [];
            var targetObj1 = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < dict1.length; i++) {
                for (var key in dict1[i]) {

                    if (!targetObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        targetObj[key]= 0;
                        //targetObj1.push(targetObj);
                    }
   targetObj[key] += (dict1[i][key]);
}}

Comment: I am getting problem in this part only, If I will remove this "+"  from targetObj[key] += (dict1[i][key]);

Comment: then it will store only 1 value for 1 key combination and If I am Adding "+" sign, then it is giving like [object, object]

Comment: Right, that is why I suggested the solution in my answer. Set and append to  proper arrays instead and you won't have that problem of your objects being converted to strings and then appended to the existing string value.

Comment: Yes Now I am gettiong what I want but How to print the values, If i am Printing it to my console, it is giving the values for column but not giving the value of that row

Comment: 'LME,ZB,201703': 
   [ { 'a:Account': [Object],
       'a:AlgoName': [Object],
       'a:AvgPrice': [Object],
       'a:BeginString': [Object],
       'a:BodyLength': [Object],
       'a:ChildAccount': [Object],
       'a:ClOrdId': [Object],
       'a:ContractName': [Object],
       'a:CurrentUser': [Object],
       'a:CustomerOrFirm': [Object],

Comment: Now I am gettiong the output like above,